# How to handle this firebase deploy erros?

Tags: firebase

I'm facing this problem while deploying my project on firebase
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I65HS.png

Answer (score 1):

In your file `firebase.json` check the field `public`.

It might be necessary to point it to `build/your-project-name` and not only to `build/`.

This is the most common solution, if it does not help, please post your `firebase.json`.